# Download file using python from sharepoint's generated link (Copy link)

Tags: office365apis, python

I'm looking for a python way to download a SharePoint URL which looks like this:

```
https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/:v:/s/<site_name>/EWrCISgzqYFOj8SAHhogWCcBuKyGUDTsy6dENyFJgb_l_w?e=r8KVDN
```

`<tenant>` and `<site_name>` are being masked for security reasons.

The above link is being generated using the `Copy link` option available in sharepoint web interface as shown in below pictures:

- [image]
- [image]
- [image]

**Is there a way to download the file with the link, `username` and `password` using python libraries.**

**Note 1:** The generated link is not public and it can only be downloaded by the users who are having access.

**Note 2:** I've already used a python library named `Office365-REST-Python-Client` to download the file using a service relative URL: `https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/<site_name>/<folder>/<subfolder>/1Welcome Card.mp4`. What I'm looking for a way to download a file which has a URL as mentioned above.